# como convertir fecha string a datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una fecha en el siguiente formato 10/16/2018 o sea esta en formato MM/DD/YYYY asi llega como parametro, pero esta fecha esta como string y necesito convertirla a un datetime, probe lo siguiente:

```
string fecha = "10/16/2018";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(fecha);
```

Y me genera este error: no se puede reconocer la cadena como valor datetime valido, por favor ayuda, sin embargo cuando la fecha esta en formato DD/MM/YYYY si me funciona, pero obligatoriamente debo tener la fecha en el formato de arriba. Gracias

Comment: Tenes que pasarle el formato de la cadena  de entrada, leiste la documentacion de Pase? es mas, deberias usar ParseExact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer es una conversión de string a datetime con el formato MM/dd/yyyy, para ello es necesario que establezcas el formato correcto tal cual como este **MM/dd/yyyy**, te dejo un ejemplo:

Es necesaria la librería: `using System.Globalization;`

```
string dateString = "10/16/2018";
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Tambien lo puedes ver en funcionamiento en este [link de rextester](https://rextester.com/TKNK9480)

Comment: Perfecto me funciono muchas gracias Jorge

Comment: Genial @RaidelFonseca sí te funcionó no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar tu problema tenes que usar [DateTime.ParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) o [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2), ambas permiten ingresar el formato del `string` entrante

```
string fecha = "10/16/2018";
string formato = "MM/dd/yyyy" //MM representa Mes, dd día e yyyy año
```

Tras definir estos dos datos, ya podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
  bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(fecha, formato, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt);

    //En caso de que result sea verdadero, implica que la fecha alojada en el string es válida.
    if(result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La fecha es correcta y es {0}", dt.ToShortDateString());
    }
    //Caso contrario, la fecha es invalida.
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El formato de la fecha ingresada es incorrecta.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta conversión:
debes agregar [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b28bx3bh(v=vs.110).aspx) ya que con las fechas americanas los meses los usan al inicio
y puede darte error.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("10/16/2018", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

no olvides agregar el espacio de nombre **using System.Globalization;**

Un saludo